# What content-disposition to use when giving response to a cURL request?

Tags: csv, http-headers, content-disposition

Let's say we have a client (which is actually a server side PHP script), and a server (which is a server side PHP script too).

The client makes a HTTP request to the server via `cURL`. The client accepts `text/csv`, so the corresponding header is set and the client would like to save the response into a file, so the `CURLOPT_FILE` option is properly set.

The question is whether the server when serving the request and sends back the CSV "encoded" content, should it use the `inline` or the `attachment` as the value for `Content-Disposition` header?

A very simple pseudo-code for testing: the server does something like this:

```
if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
    header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for internet explorer
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Length:".filesize($attachment_location));
    header("Content-Disposition: inline");
    readfile($attachment_location);
    die();
} else {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not found");
}
```

Or should it be something like:

```
<?php
$attachment_location = "./c3m.csv";

if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
    header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for internet explorer
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-Length:".filesize($attachment_location));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=c3m.csv");
    readfile($attachment_location);
    die();
} else {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not found");
}
```

Comment: There is no "Content-Transfer-Encoding" header field in HTTP.

Comment: Julian is right: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#appendix-A.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL doesn't care about the Content-Disposition, so it should have no bearing on what value you give it.